# How to find vectors with minimum distance from two vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vector-spaces

Say we are working with vectors in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space and are given subspaces $U = \{u_1, \ldots, u_k\}$ and  $V = \{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$ $(k < n)$ is there a method for finding $\displaystyle\operatorname*{argmin}_{(u,v) \in U \times V} \|u - v \|^2$ where $\|u\| = \|v\| = 1$?

i.e.; I am trying to find two $n$-dimensional unit vectors $u$ and $v,$ each being some linear combination of $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$ and and $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$ respectively, that are as close to each other as possible (using $L_2$ distance).

Comment: Do you mean unit vectors? In other case the minimum is zero, because zero is a common vector.

Comment: @mfl good point... yes unit vectors (perhaps the linear weights should sum to 1).